# How to generate changelog from Trac

Tags: bug-tracking, trac, changelog

I need to generate changelog from Trac for a specific version as XML and then process it with a custom XSL. It seems one of the default reports is the case (All Tickets By Milestone (Including closed)). However, if i request it as  XML  (by adding format=rss to the url) the output XML does not contain Status, Resolution, Milestone fields. How do i configure it to contain all the fields? How do you generate your changelogs from Trac to include it in release notes?

Answer (score 1):

1) Please provide a copy of the Query (Click on SQL Query link at the bottom of the page)

What I find strange is that normally you get more columns in the CSV/RSS-XML reports than in the HTML version (see Wiki page TracReports and the extract below)

2) Personally I generate my changelogs directly from Trac into pdf. I personalised the SQL statement as much as possible to get what I want. I prefer to get a result quickly and economically rather than spand a lot of time to get exactly what I want.

===== TracReports extract =====

*column -- Hide data. Prepending an underscore ('*') to a column name instructs Trac to hide the contents from the HTML output. This is useful for information to be visible only if downloaded in other formats (like CSV or RSS/XML).

Comment: Thanks for your response! I can't see SQL Query link (perhaps of the permissions, i'm a regular dev). What i've found that requesting the same report in CSV,TAB,HTML formats always return all the columns i need (i specify them in the query url). However, changing 'format' parameter to rss hides most of the columns. The version is 0.11.4.