# Is it possible to generate a changelog automatically from Trac?

Tags: bug-tracking, trac, changelog

**Does Trac provide a way to automate generation of change logs from a group of tickets?** I'm interesting in giving a list of completed tickets to someone with access to Trac, preferably in a human readable format, something like a word doc or plaintext.

If Trac doesn't provide this functionality directly is there an external tool I can use?

Note that I am aware of the question [How to generate changelog from Trac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520479/how-to-generate-changelog-from-trac) and it doesn't help me.

Comment: As you must have already noticed by now is, there's no dedicated function in Trac for changelog creation. So you'll want to use the report/query interface, that certainly can harvest ticket data and has grouping/summarizing capability for a changelog-like report. Depending on your specific needs this could be enough, if you take some time to customize. *Ultimately* you need to *provide more details on your needs*, or this question is too unclear to hope for a satisfying answer. Note too, that for Trac itself there's a dedicated wiki page with more than what ticket data alone can deliver.

Comment: @hasienda, you should change your comment to an answer

Comment: I thought to come up with a real answer as soon as more details would be available. Anyway, done so. I'll try to extend it, to respond as needed/requested. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you must have already noticed by now is, there's no dedicated function in Trac for changelog creation.

So you'll want to use the report/query interface, that certainly can harvest ticket data and has grouping/summarizing capability for a changelog-like report. Depending on your specific needs this could be enough, if you take some time to customize. *Ultimately* you need to *provide more details* on your needs, or this question is too unclear to hope for a satisfying answer.

Note too, that for Trac itself there's a dedicated wiki page with more than what ticket data alone can deliver.

Answer (score 0):

How much information do you need in this "list of completed tickets"?  One thing I've done before is create a report that shows the desired information and then "print" the page to a PDF file using one of the many PDF-creation utilities available.  You can also use a tool like `wget` to grab the results in HTML format from a script.

Comment: Yeah I ended up just printing off a copy of the report, which is basically what you are describing. I just wanted to get it in a more readable format.

Comment: If the data is already there and the issue is merely formatting, you can go a long way by writing some custom CSS.  I use a browser plugin called Greasemonkey to inject custom CSS into a Trac page when I want to alter the page layout/format for generating reports.  Since it's a browser plugin, it only affects my local machine and not other Trac users.